# How to get sysdate - 5 days in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to get sysdate-5days in jsp how to get that ?

to get today date I have used the following scripts

```
<% 
SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date                     = new Date();
String sysdate              = formatter.format(date);
%>
```

how to get sysdate - 5 days and tell me how to compare this sysdate - 5 days from form calendar value(document.f1.day.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `java.util.Calendar` instead of `java.util.Date`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);//note the -ve value
String date = fmt.format(cal.getTime());
```

[Demo here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/zclrlR)

Now you can assign the value to the javascript variable:

```
<script>
  var jsDate = '<%=date%>';
</script>
```

or compare it directly:

```
<script>
  if(document.f1.day.value === '<%=date%>') {
     //to do here
  }
</script>
```